How to convert signed byte to int32
I have signed byte. How can I convert it to signed integer (32 bit).
I use x86 assembler.
Now its look like:
            mov ebx, 0
            mov bl, [edi]
            test bl, 0x80
            jz l3
            or ebx, 0xFFFFFF00
l3:

But I think its not very effective.

Use a movsx instruction.

You could replace all this code with movsx ebx, byte [edi] That takes the byte at memory address [edi] and sign extends it to a 32-bit integer in EBX.

Instead of test bl, 80h \ jz you could also use test bl, bl \ jns

Its not compare with 0. Its test bit 8 (sign)

You say "Its not compare with 0." But it is, or at least can be. You could easily have written cmp bl, 0 jge l3. What I and @ecm show you are alternative instructions that yield the same result in your code snippet, and in case of what @ecm proposed it would be 1 byte shorter encoded.

Possibly I can use movsx? I dont need to use jmp if I have movsx. I dont need to write code 1 byte shorter (why i need it at all?)

As stated you can replace all of your example code by a single movsx instruction. My addition was just a comment on how your code could be improved without completely replacing it. test bl, bl does set the Zero Flag according to whether bl is zero but it also sets the Sign Flag according to the top most-significant bit of the bl register which happens to be exactly the sign bit that you want to test in your variant by using test bl, 80h. If you do not understand that, note how I changed your jnz to jns, a different condition. As @SepRoland test bl, bl is shorter.

Thanks! I realize, that didnt undertand first two comments (And I didnt say "thanks, works fine"). And movsx not working. Lets use strange compares like test bl, bl, which change also sign flag! What would i do without you very perfect comment.
